# The cursor disappear when pressing the right arrow key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

A content editable div has html elements like spans and simple text.

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilsahu/oct06dz8/4/)

```css
.ing-tag_0{
color:white;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div value="" id="step_input_0" name="step" placeholder="Tell us about step 1" class="input stepbox step_input" contenteditable="true">sdf dsaf asdf s <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span><span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span><span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span><span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span><span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span><span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span><span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span><span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span><span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span></div>
```

Move the cursor to the end of the div. On hitting left arrows key continuously from the end of the  the cursor moves in between the spans continuously .This works fine.

Now move the cursor to the start of the div then try moving to the right side of div by hitting right arrows keys continuously then the cursor disappears at some point when it encounters the spans.

Where I wrong here.

Please suggest a way so If I press right arrow the cursor moves to end by passing thru the div.?

**The span must not be content editable as these are fixed.**

***EDIT***

I dont have any other option to change this. I already tried adding spaces of zero width.

1. This did not work on safari.
2. What if user deletes this spaces. Again the cursor would disappear.

Comment: Looks alot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215933/get-and-set-the-position-of-the-cursor-in-content-editable-div?noredirect=1 just different user

Comment: If you are also "ser cha" then there is no point of making the same question again

Comment: I cant follow the link

Comment: Of course not, it's just been deleted, funny how that happened when i linked it.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Small world. Please suggest a fix bro

Comment: Sorry but you deleted all the other suggestions I made in your previous question. Not gonna repeat my self.

Comment: None of the fix works . I cant add spaces in between the spans

Comment: The lesson of the day: Just because its been 20 min without a working solution from someone, does not mean you have to delete the question and make a new one.

Comment: Ser Cha is a friend. I did not know about it. He showed me the issue. I asked here

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works:

```
$('.editable').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (window.getSelection && event.which === 39) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        var nodes = sel.anchorNode.childNodes;
        var selection = sel.anchorOffset;
        var loops = 0;
        var i = selection;
        if (nodes.length > 0 || (nodes.length === 0 && sel.anchorNode.length === 
        selection && sel.anchorNode.nextSibling !== null)) {
            var r = document.createRange();
            if (nodes.length === 0 && sel.anchorNode.length === selection && 
            sel.anchorNode.nextSibling !== null) {
                r.setStartBefore(sel.anchorNode.nextSibling);
                r.setEndAfter(sel.anchorNode.nextSibling);
            } else {
                while (i < nodes.length) {
                    loops += 1;
                    if (nodes[i].nodeType !== 3) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                r.setEnd(this, selection + loops);
                r.setStart(this, selection);
            }
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(r);
            $(this).focus();
        }
    }
});
```

[Example including backspace event](https://codepen.io/sguerrero/pen/Gapepy)

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem. This usually happens when two contenteditable= "false"  elements are placed placed together. I have solved this issue by adding a buffer node between these two concurrent non editable nodes.

```html
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
  <span contenteditable="false">Node 1</span>
  <span class="bufferNode"></span>
  <span contenteditable="false">Node 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add spaces in between each of your `<span>`'s. At the end, inside the div put a zero-width space (`&#8203;`). Hopefully this solved your problem!

```css
.ing-tag_0{
color: white;
background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div value="" id="step_input_0" name="step" placeholder="Tell us about step 1" class="input stepbox step_input" contenteditable="true">sdf dsaf asdf s <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span> <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span> <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span> <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span> <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span> <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span> <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span> <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span> <span data-class="method" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> sdfcxz </span>&#8203;</div>
```